# Парсинг на PHP

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Написал код парсинга контента:

```
ini_get('safe_mode') or set_time_limit(0);
function request($url,$post = 0){
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'http://www.test.ru/';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $post!==0 );
if($post)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html(request('http://test.ru/'));
if($html->innertext!='' and
count($html->find('#holliday_prices'))){
    foreach($html->find('#holliday_prices') as $blok){
           echo $blok;
}
}
```

Как изменить адреса ссылок в полученном контенте($blok)?
Адреса ссылок все разные.

Comment: Для начала вам необходимо отформатировать текст Вашего вопроса. Перейдите в режим редактирования сообщения, выделите приведенный вами код, и нажмите на кнопку 101010. 
Далее, Вас интересуют ссылки, находящиеся в атрибуте href тэгов <a>?

Comment: Извиняюсь за не подобающий вид моего вопроса. Исправил.
Да именно они.
Мне не понятно как это сделать именно вырезанном блоке ($blok).
Сейчас ссылки имеют вид: <a href="/route/mow/bcn" title="..." >11805</a>
А нужно чтобы было так: <a href="http://www.test.ru" title="..." >11805</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, попробуйте такой подход:

```
<?
$html = <<<HTML
<div id="headnav">
 <a href="/" rel="home"><img src="/images/php.gif"
 alt="PHP" width="120" height="67" id="phplogo" /></a>
 <div id="headmenu">
  <a href="/downloads.php">downloads</a> |
  <a href="/docs.php">documentation</a> |
  <a href="/FAQ.php">faq</a> |
  <a href="/support.php">getting help</a> |
  <a href="/mailing-lists.php">mailing lists</a> |
  <a alt="alt text" href="/license">licenses</a> |
  <a href="https://wiki.php.net/">wiki</a> |
  <a href="https://bugs.php.net/">reporting bugs</a> |
  <a href="/sites.php">php.net sites</a> |
  <a href="/conferences/">conferences</a> |
  <a href="/my.php">my php.net</a>
 </div>
</div>
HTML;
$newurl = "http://xternalx.com/";

echo preg_replace('#(\<a[^\>]*href\=\")(.*?)(\"\>)#', "$1{$newurl}$3", $html);
```

Comment: ОГРОМНО спасибо, получилось:) жаль не могу поставить палец вверх..

Comment: А можно решить задачу не регулярками? как здесь:
foreach( $html->find('#holliday_prices a') as $a){
$a->href =
str_replace('http://www.test.ru/','http://test2.ru',$a->href);
}
echo $html->find('#holliday_prices',0)->innertext;
Пример рабочий, только он правит конкретный урл, а нужно все. К сожалению они не похожи.

Comment: Можно. Не знаю, как это делается в пхп, рекурсивно, или можно что-то типа xpath использовать.  Самый простой способ - рекурсивно пройтись по всем элементам документа, и проверить, есть ли из них кто-то с названием 'a'. Если есть, то меняем атрибут href у него на нужный, и вуа-ля! :]