# Смена кодировки при парсинге

Tags: кодировка, перекодировка, php, синтаксический-анализ

Здесь непосредственно лежит [скрипт парсинга](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/148647/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php):

Ситуация в следующем:
  Сайт который парситься, у него кодировка UTF8, а скрипт парсинга выводится на сайте с кодировкой WIN1251.
  Подскажите как произвести замену кодировок при парсинге с **UTF8** на **win1251**?
Сейчас при вставки скрипта на сайте выводится не понятно что.
Буду весьма благодарен вашей помощи.

Comment: смотрите в сторону iconv[1]
   [http://php.net/manual/ru/book.iconv.php][1]

Comment: спасибо, решил следующим образом: $string = @iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1251//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не всегда есть возможность использовать `iconv()`.

[`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

Answer (score 1):

спасибо, решил следующим образом:

```
$string = @iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1251//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
```